# How to prevent from redirecting to other activity after signup?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

This code is working fine till public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) but right after its execution, the activity redirects to the previous activity instead of staying on it, and then the toast message appears.

I want it to stay on the activity after registering the user.

mFireBaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mfirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

```
    mFireBaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(e_mail, password).addOnCompleteListener(StudentSignUp.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
        {

            if(!task.isSuccessful())
            {

                Toast.makeText(StudentSignUp.this, "Please check your network or try again using different E-mail.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //loadingBar.dismiss();

            }

            else
            {

                StudentDetails studentCredentials = new StudentDetails( studentId, name, e_mail, password );
                String uId = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                mfirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Student").child(uId).setValue(studentCredentials).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                    {

                        Toast.makeText(StudentSignUp.this, "Your Student is Registered & account has been created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //loadingBar.dismiss();

                    }

                });

            }

        }

    });

}
```

Comment: Is your second activity crashing your app? If yes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to pass the context in the onCompleteListener.

The code should be like:

```
  mFireBaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(e_mail, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
{

    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
    {

        if(!task.isSuccessful())
        {

            Toast.makeText(StudentSignUp.this, "Please check your network or try again using different E-mail.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //loadingBar.dismiss();

        }

        else
        {

            StudentDetails studentCredentials = new StudentDetails( studentId, name, e_mail, password );
            String uId = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
            mfirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Student").child(uId).setValue(studentCredentials).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>()
            {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid)
                {

                    Toast.makeText(StudentSignUp.this, "Your Student is Registered & account has been created.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //loadingBar.dismiss();

                }

            });

        }

    }

});
```

And instead of using onCompleteListener and then if(!task.isSuccessful()), you can also use **onSuccessListener**, and sometimes we forget to check if(!task.isSuccessful()) so better use onSuccessListener

**Feel free to ask if something is unclear.** Kindly mark this as the correct answer if it helps you and also in future this answer can help other needy.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with OnCompleteListener it is working as I desired but on the execution of onSuccessListener my activity crashes i don't understand why because logcat is also not showing any error on any line please help me if you understand my query.

Comment: There is no log??

Comment: In the run section have you looked there?

Comment: I don't know how to look in the run section but when I debug it line by line the variable aVoid appears to have null inside it ... is that the reason ?